# Can an unversioned file be easily upgraded

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch

We want to be able to patch our product in the future by producting an ".msp". A particular exe in the .msi is missing version information.

If we create an .msp in the future, will we have problems upgrading that .exe?

I want to know whether we need to add the version information and rebuild the .msi or whether we can avoid it so we don't have to repeat our release process for the .msi.

Comment: If you don't want to version the file then it will be replaced : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx but it's better to use file hashes so Windows can determine a change in a data file, but better yet is to start using file versions because it's the best reliable way to update binaries as well as identify them, and is what "everyone" uses.

Answer (score 0):

This post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/30/458295.aspx
explains that a versioned file will always replace an unversioned one. So, as long as the any updated version of this exe is given version information before it gets put in a .msp, then it should upgrade ok.